# Polygon merge/combine with multiple line paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (https://www.tutpad.com/tut/how-to-create-a-polygonal-background-in-adobe-illustrator) to create my own low poly background, except I can't seem to properly group the paths and use the direct selection tool to make the polygon irregular like shown in the tutorial.

[image: illustrator paths]

The tutorial says to create the lines using the pen tool from the corners of the polygon to its center. Then it says to group everything and you when use the direct selection tool, you can change the shape which makes it easier to manipulate the triangles. However, this doesn't work for me, and at this point I don't think it's possible. The lines share anchor points and I thought there would be a way to sorta tell illustrator to combine it with the polygon instead of having it as separate paths.

Can you even have those paths combined and be able to move a single anchor point which will essentially warp the rest of the shape?

Using Illustrator CC 2017 on Windows.

EDIT: I couldn't figure out a better way to explain it in the title, so if this does get answered, it'd be helpful if you could suggest a better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Won't try to merge/combine the Anchors. I need 3 steps:

1st, Use "Direct Selection Tool" (Default Shortcuts 'A');

2nd, (Important!) Drag you mouse to select the polygon & line's anchors together.

3rd, Use direction keys on Keyboard, or drag and move with Selection Tool (Shortcuts 'V').

Finished!!

Comment: Thank you, at the time, I was selecting either a single anchor point or the entire thing and tried to reshape it. Now I know to select the parts I want to move in that instant.

Comment: Wow, but I can't believe it's the only way. That's how I managed to do it as well, but I was sure there should be some kind of joining the points? (I've faced with the same tutorial and it sounds there like there is an option to do that) Because another problem for this is to then move those points and snap to another shape point.